# HTTP/2 Enabled ALPN supported but my site get HTTP/1.1

Tags: configuration, debian, apache2, http2

**Hello community !**

I search on all related post a solution to my problem but nothing run for me...

Actually I try to configure my apache 2 server, I follow some tutorial and it seems to me that I did everything correctly.
After check with https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test & https://http2.pro/ it says that my server supports HTTP/2.

But then I try to load my website all requests are made in http/1.1 (I try with `curl` command and check it with chrome network).

I don't understand where the problem is ... (I'm sorry if I haven't provided all the necessary information but I'm still a beginner in server management)

Thank you for the time you have taken to read my problem, hoping to have answers from you!

Comment: Post your `curl` command. Are you using `curl --http2`?

Comment: I use ```curl -v https://ag-dev.fr/```
and that return me :

```SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55e9ce1b6e90)
> GET / HTTP/1.1```

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
curl --http2 https://ag-dev.fr/
```

and it returns correctly an HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=fr><head><title>Portfolio</title>...
```

Comment: After consultation with a colleague I managed to make sure that HTTP2 was used correctly. However, by checking my console for my part, requests continue to be made with HTTP1.1 (even after emptying my cache and going into private browsing) while for my colleague it is done well in HTTP2. I do not understand why...

Comment: You probably have a transparent proxy that converts your traffic from HTTP/2 to HTTP/1.1?

Comment: If so, I am not aware of it. I wonder if this can come from my antivirus (Bitdefender) or my antimalware (Malwarebytes).

Comment: It could well come from anti-* you have installed. Disable them entirely for this test.

Comment: I test without it and got HTTP1.1 get don't understand why.

Comment: Next option is that you use `wireshark` to capture the network trace. You will have to decrypt it, but there are tutorials online that show how. See what goes out from your computer, and see what arrives at the server.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Bitdefender protection shield worked for me.